# Express File Upload (React, Express, MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, antd

i am try to upload files from front-end to back-end.However, i keep getting 400 bad request. 
Can someone help me? Thank you so much!

**Here is my package version**

```
"express": "^4.17.1",
"mongoose": "^5.7.3",
"react": "^16.9.0",
"reqwest": "^2.0.5",
"antd": "^3.23.0",
"express-fileupload": "^1.1.6-alpha.6",
```

**Here is my back-end** If i remove the if statement and save a typical model, then no error occurs. Therefore, i think the req.files is not working.

```
const express = require('express')
const Router = express.Router()
const app = express();
Router.use(fileUpload());

Router.post('/addFile', function(req, res){
        if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
            return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
        }


})
```

**Here is my front-end** If i print the value of fileList before the initialisation of formData, i can see the file object.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Upload, Button, Icon, message} from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import reqwest from 'reqwest';  

class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fileList: [],
    uploading: false,
  }

  handleUpload = () => {
    const { fileList } = this.state;
    // multipart/form-data
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file1', fileList[0]);   

    this.setState({
      uploading: true,
    });

    // You can use any AJAX library you like
    reqwest({
      url: '/user/addFile',   
      method: 'post',
      processData: false,
      data: formData,
      success: () => {
        this.setState({
          fileList,
          uploading: false,
        });
        message.success('upload successfully.');
      },
      error: () => {
        this.setState({
          uploading: false,
        });
        message.error('upload failed.');
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { uploading, fileList } = this.state;
    const props = {
      onRemove: (file) => {
        this.setState((state) => {
          const index = state.fileList.indexOf(file);
          const newFileList = state.fileList.slice();
          newFileList.splice(index, 1);
          return {
            fileList: newFileList,
          };
        });
      },
      beforeUpload: (file) => {
        this.setState(state => ({
          fileList: [...state.fileList, file],
        }));
        return false;
      },
      fileList,
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Upload {...props}>
          <Button>
            <Icon type="upload" /> Select File
          </Button>
        </Upload>
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={this.handleUpload}
          disabled={fileList.length === 0}
          loading={uploading}
          style={{ marginTop: 16 }}
        >
          {uploading ? 'Uploading' : 'Start Upload' }
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Demo;
```

Comment: What happens when you log the request object in your server route? It looks as though you are sending the file with the key `file1`. Perhaps `req.files` is undefined and maybe it should be `req.file1`?

Comment: @seanulus It does not work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you show us a log of req.files?

Answer (score 0):

req.files.file1 & I see a couple issues with your server side code.

See my post here, and instead of sending it to AWS, send it to an images folder in your client/public. Also, make sure to address cross origin resource sharing. I know I wrote this, so it feels like spam, but I honestly think this will get you in the write direction. If it doesn’t, I apologize for the distraction.

Use file.mv to move it client/public/images [after you name it.](https://link.medium.com/U1SdsoHMy2)